# Align 3 divs side by side with one column having 2

Tags: css, html

I have a total of 3 divs - how to get them to appear as per the following image.

I can get 2 together using float:left, however withe 3rd one keeps sitting underneath div A.

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with `A {float:left}` or `B, C {float:right}` and specifying the widths?

Comment: Make 2 columns. Place div A in first, place div B  and div C in other.

Comment: ExP - using float right div C sits to the right but below divA

Comment: CSS float will clear the row after the tallest element in the previous row, therefore bumping C under A regardless of the float direction.

Comment: Did it using srijans method

Answer (score 2):

Check out [masonry.js](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

The reason why floats cannot be used in this case is that the float will clear after the tallest element in the row, therefore bumping element C under element A.

Alternatively, you can place A in a sub-parent floated to the left, and B and C in a sub-parent floated to the right. However, this makes dictating the order of items in a responsive/fluid layout difficult. The solution can be simplified as follow:

```
<div>
    <div class="col">
        <!-- A -->
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <!-- B + C -->
    </div>
</div>
```

---

For the CSS:

```
.col { float: left; width 50%; }
```

Comment: Would really appreciate if people actually leave feedback for why the answer is not useful.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap B and C in additional div similar to A (with float left as well)